# Ruby: Undefined method error on method called AFTER definition

Tags: ruby

I am not sure what's happening here...but say I do this:

```
def who_wins?(choice1, choice2)
    if (choice1 == 'R' && choice2 == 'S') || (choice1 == 'S' && choice2 == 'P') || (choice1 == 'P' && choice2 == 'R')
        return choice1
    elsif choice1 == choice2
        return "tie"
    else
        raise NoSuchStrategyError
    end
end

won_wins?('R', 'P')
```

It gives me the following error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `won_wins?' for main:Object

at top level    in my-file.rb at line 25
```

Why would it do that, even though I am calling the method AFTER the definition?

Comment: Because you named your method `who_wins?` and you're trying to call `won_wins?` ?

Comment: In addition to the fact that this is an typing error, you are trying to raise a class, not an error of the class. What you want is `raise NoSuchStratagyError.new`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...typo #fail on my part. @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh thanks for pointing that out, you are right. I do want an instance of the class rather than the actual class. But, out of curiostiy, why does it work if I do `raise NoSuchStrategyError`?

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? It was a simple mistake. Surely we all make those from time-to-time.

Comment: @marcamillion: In Ruby, classes are objects of class `Class` (there is no good way to say that). So when you `raise NoSuchStratagyError`, you are still raising an object, just not the one you thought you were. If your interesting in Ruby metaprogramming and Ruby programming in general, you might like `Programing Ruby 1.9: The Pragmatic Programer's Guide` by the Pragmatic Programers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typed `won_wins?` and not `who_wins?`